# Is there an equivalent in NodeJS to how Vite transforms imports?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I'm new to using the ESM mechanism and Vite. When I was developing a frontend with Vite and TypeScript, I noticed that even when the `type` in `package.json` is set to `module`, I could import files without needing to add the `.js` extension. Additionally, I was able to utilize the syntax `import { Class } from "commonjs-lib"`. Now, I want to adapt some of my frontend code for a NodeJS project. However, in NodeJS, when using ESM, I'm required to include the `.js` suffix in my imports, and I'm limited to the `import lib from "commonjs-lib"` syntax. This means I can't directly run my frontend code in this environment. Are there any tools available that could help me make similar changes for NodeJS, making its behavior align with what I experienced in Vite?

Comment: Use babel , it's the same thing that vite is using

Comment: @Konrad Which plugin should I use?

Comment: maybe this library can help.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ebx